# Безопасно ли сравнение == для типа double?

Tags: c++, сравнение

```
double d = -1;

if (d==-1) { }
```

1. При каких обстоятельствах, безопасность сравнения на `==` становится низкой? Надо переменную умножить, поделить или что, чтобы `double` начал показывать погрешность вроде не `0`, а `0.00000001`, и приходится применять эпсилон, а не простое сравнение.
2. В настройках компилятора есть опция: *Модель вычислений с плавающий точкой (точный, строгий, быстрый)*. На что она влияет, если установлено "*быстрый*", то `double` будет не точно работать?

Comment: Что такое "безопасность" в вашем понимании? Да, безопасно сравнивать - компьютер не взорвется, и с вашей карты никто денег не снимет.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Отвечаю по-пунктам:

1. Нельзя сравнивать два числа с плавующей запятой между собой, из за того, что числа с плавующей запятой не могут быть представлены точно, по-этому мы не можем полагаться на оператор сравнения.

   Популярная практика сравнения такая:

   ```
   #include <cmath>
   #include <limits>

   bool is_equal(double x, double y) {
       return std::fabs(x - y) < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
   }
   ```

   Можно задавать свой "эпсилон".
2. Как я понял, речь идет о MS VC++.
   Опции компилятора описаны тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e7s85ffb.aspx
   Если выбрать fast, то не будет соблюдаться стандарт IEEE 754. Не будут работать сравнения с Nan и пр.

Answer (score 14):

Сравнение на строгое равенство почти никогда не безопасно. Вместо него следует использовать `fabs(x-y) < EPS`, где `EPS` - это некая константа, например, `1e-7`.

Единственный случай, когда можно позволить себе строгое сравнение - это если есть некая константа, которую ты мог сам присвоить (явно, без вычислений), и с которой сравниваешь для того, чтобы узнать, было ли переприсваивание. И даже в этом месте надо быть осторожным, потому что известны случаи, когда благодаря оптимизации у сравниваемых величин оказывается разный тип, что приводит к разной точности и неравенству.

Ещё все вычисления с целыми числами до 2<sup>53</sup> точные. Это используется языками с единственным числовым типом (например js). Однако, если ты уверен, что значение целое, то зачем вообще использовать `double`? Лучше взять 64-битный целый тип.

Answer (score 5):

Если вы хотите сравнить два `double`, лучше всего использовать такое сравнение (после знака `<` вы указываете до какого знака после запятой вас интересует сравнение):

```
#include <cmath>

double L, R;

if( abs(L-R) < 0.00001 )
```

Если `if` выполнился - два ваших `double` равны.

Comment: Чем этот ответ отличается от других?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я думаю, что новичкам этот способ будет понятнее, он не использует никаких функций

Comment: Так мой тоже не использует :)

Answer (score 3):

Такой вариант сравнения чисел с плавающей точкой предлагают разработчики Qt:

```
Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR static inline bool qFuzzyCompare(double p1, double p2)
{
    return (qAbs(p1 - p2) * 1000000000000. <= qMin(qAbs(p1), qAbs(p2)));
}

Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR static inline bool qFuzzyCompare(float p1, float p2)
{
    return (qAbs(p1 - p2) * 100000.f <= qMin(qAbs(p1), qAbs(p2)));
}
```

Здесь Эпсилон зависит от самих сравниваемых чисел. Но чем это лучше - сказать не могу.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, будет ли полезен для Вас мой совет. При считывании из файла точек некоторой зависимости - приведенных с некоторым шагом (0.1) по абсциссе или со случайным шагом, я, обычно, без ущерба для точности стараюсь абсциссы выразить с помощью двоичных дробей (знаменатель = 2^n). Например, 0.1 =~ 51/512. А затем, с помощью интерполяции изменяю абсциссы и ординаты. Тогда сравнения ==, < и > становятся корректными. Много времени интерполяция данных не занимает и на точность практически не влияет.