# Где логическая ошибка в php условии?

Tags: php, задание-на-собеседовании

Полный текст вопроса: В какой из перечисленных строк кода присутствует потенциальная логическая ошибка сравнения дробных чисел?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правильных ответов может быть несколько.

1) Я не очень понимаю вопрос. Что имеют ввиду под "потенциальная логическая ошибка"?

2) Все сравнения которые есть я набил проверил http://ideone.com/xNE6TB не true только вторая строка:

```
2-0.8 === 1+1.2
```

Но я так понял что она не true не потому что там логическая ошибка, а тупо цифры разные выходит сравниваем 1.2 и 2.2 Но ответ только вторая строчка не верен.
Помогите нубу кто чем может с разъяснениями.

Comment: `var_dump(15/3 === 5.0);`

Comment: Оба ответивших вас нагло обманули :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 6 / 5 === 1.2

5 не является степенью 2, поэтому дробь точно не представима.
Сравнивать на равенство не стоит.

> 2 - 0.8 === 1 + 1.2

То же, что в прошлый раз.
Плюс, что-то эти числа вообще не равны.

> abs(6 / 5 - 1.2) < 0.0001

Это правильная форма проверки первого равенства.
Хотя я бы поставил `1e-7` вместо `1e-4`.

> 1.2 === 1.2

По идее, две литеральные константы между собой равны. Но это странно.
Связанный вопрос: [Безопасно ли сравнение == для типа double?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/399420/178988)

> 0.0001 > abs (6 / 5 - 1.2)

Верная форма сравнения на `!==` для первого пункта.

Comment: `var_dump(6 / 5 === 1.2);` --> `bool(true)`, `var_dump(1.2 === 1.2);` --> `bool(true)`.

Comment: @Visman, вопрос: _"потенциальная логическая ошибка"_, т. е. то, что два неточно представленных числа в данном случае совпадают не важно. Важно, что они точно не представимы, поэтому _потенциальная_ ошибка тут есть.

Comment: Во-втором случае (`1.2 === 1.2`) нет, в первом согласен - есть.

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае используются числа с плавающей точкой, [в документации на сайте](http://www.php.net/float) по поводу их точности есть даже раздел, выделенный красным. Эти числа не имеют точного внутреннего представления и их точность считается примерно до 14-го знака после запятой. Дальше в числе может идти любой мусор, это может выдавать неожиданный результат.

К примеру, то же сравнение `6/5 === 1.2`, вполне может быть представлено в памяти как `6/5 === 1.2000000000000004`, а итог сравнения как `1.19999999999998 == 1.2000000000000004`. Поэтому с такими числами нужна аккуратность в обращении. Как правило числа сравнивают с какой-либо малой разностью `abs(6/5 - 1.2) < 0.00001`. Сравнивать их прямым `==` или `===` считается логической ошибкой, поскольку является бомбой замедленного действия.

Поэтому получаем:

```
6/5 === 1.2 - неверно 
2-0.8 === 1+1.2 - спорно, но можно считать верным (всегда false)
abs(6/5 - 1.2) < 0.0001 - верно
1.2 === 1.2 - неверно
0.0001 > abs(6/5 - 1.2) - верно
```

Comment: "неверно" - это те строки где есть потенциальная логическая ошибка да? А 1.2 === 1.2 неверно именно из-за того что там числа с плавающей точкой тоже?

Comment: @RoboNoob, да, строки с потенциальной логической ошибкой помечены как "неверно". В том числе проверка `1.2 === 1.2` хоть и будет работать в 99% случаев, но т.к. там числа с плавающей точкой, остается шанс получить логическую ошибку. Дело в том, что данный код может работать нормально, а может в какой-то момент перестать работать (поменяли сервер, поменяли версию PHP или просто звезды не так сошлись). Никто не гарантирует правильность такого сравнения чисел, так как после 14-го знака там может появиться все что угодно.

Comment: `var_dump(6 / 5 === 1.2);` --> `bool(true)`, `var_dump(1.2 === 1.2);` --> `bool(true)`.

Comment: @Visman, читайте внимательно информацию по предоставленным ссылкам и учите мат. часть, ваш `true` не гарантирован. То, что вы получили `bool(true)` является всего лишь частным случаем вероятности и зависит от операционной системы и реализации интерпретатора. При определенных условиях Вы можете спокойно словить `bool(false)` и интерпретатор будет прав. Даже в документации про это специально написали и выделили красным цветом.

Comment: @AlexKrass, для сравнения типа `1.2 === 1.2` всегда будет `true`.

Comment: @Visman Я вот смотрю официальную документацию и вижу, что мне никто этого не гарантирует. Смотрю IEEE 754 и опять же вижу, что мне никто это не гарантирует. Откуда Вы берете уверенность, что `1.2 === 1.2` всегда и везде будет `true`? Вы можете это хоть как-то доказать? Нельзя полагаться на недокументированное поведение, это и считается **потенциальной** логической ошибкой, которая может себя не проявлять вообще никак долгое время.

Comment: @AlexKrass, то есть в документации у вас прямо сказано, что одно и то же число может хранится по разному, в результате чего при сравнении переменных, которые содержат это число, мы получим `false`? Это же бред!

Comment: @Visman, ну это не у меня в документации сказано, а вообще относится к числам с плавающей точкой(о них много написано). Их можно считать равными только до определенной точности, несколько знаков после запятой, дальше может идти все, что угодно. В теории любая попытка прямого сравнения таких чисел является ошибкой. На практике, в выражении `1.2 === 1.2` всегда будет `true`, но общей потенциальной ошибкой это быть не перестает т.к. это не гарантировано, если что-то внутри интерпретатора PHP в будущем поменяется.

Comment: @AlexKrass, да не может такое быть не при каких условиях! Ладно если бы одно число хранили с двойной точностью, а другое с одинарной, одно в виде строки, другое в виде числа. Но строгое равенство подразумевает один тип в обеих частях сравнения.

Comment: @Visman, ну возьмите нетривиальный пример и скажите, почему данное выражение `var_dump(0.1 + 0.7, 0.8, 0.1 + 0.7 === 0.8)` дает `float(0.8) float(0.8) bool(false)`, не смотря на соблюдение типов в обоих частях.

Comment: @AlexKrass, этот пример относится к `6 / 5 === 1.2` или к `2 - 0.8 === 1 + 1.2` варианту, так как там идет вычисление перед сравнением. В варианте `1.2 === 1.2` нет ни каких вычислений.

Comment: @Visman, допустим, но я же получаю одинаковые числа `float(0.8)` и `float(0.8)`, но они не равны. Тоже самое с `1.2 === 1.2`, они равны только потому, что в исходниках PHP одинаковый код генерации. Но вот гарантий того, что в один прекрасный момент это не изменится в исходниках, нету. И если интерпретатор вдруг начнет выдавать разные последовательности для двух якобы одинаковых чисел по каким-либо причинам, предъявить ему Вы ничего не сможете. Это потенциальная ошибка, шанс столкнуться с который стремится к нулю, но все еще ошибка. Довольно узкий момент теории, на который практикам все равно.

Comment: Да нет такого в теории.