# Выдаёт - неправильно завершена декларация,помогите найти ошибку

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h> 

void main(void)
{
    double f,z,x;
    int m;
    printf("vvedite x=");
    scanf("%lf",&x);
    printf("vvedite m=");
    scanf("%d",&m);

    if( x > 10 )
        f = sin(3*x);
    else if( x < 10 ) 
        f = 3*x;
    else 
        f = cos(x);

    printf("x=%.1lf,f=%.3lf", x, f);

    switch(m){
        case 3:   z = tan(x); break;
        case 5,2: z = log(abc(-m)); break;
        default:  z = sin(m);
    }

    printf("x=%.1lf,m=%d,z=%.3lf\n", x, m, z);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот, исправил некоторые ошибки в Вашем коде, компилируется, выполняется...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 

int main()
{
    double f,z,x;
    int m;

    printf("vvedite x = ");
    scanf("%lf",&x);
    printf("vvedite m = ");
    scanf("%d",&m);

    if (x > 10.0) f = sin(3.0 * x); // сравнивать числа с пл. точкой лучше через эпсилон
    else if(x < 10.0) f = 3.0 * x;
    else f = cos(x);

    printf("x = %.1lf, f = %.3lf\n", x, f); // тут добавил \n

    switch(m)
    {
        case 3:
            z = tan(x);
            break;
        case 5: case 2: // тут была ошибка
            z = log(abs(-m)); // тут была ошибка
            break;
        default:
            z = sin(m);
            break;
    }

    printf("x = %.1lf, m = %d, z = %.3lf\n", x, m, z);

    return 0;
}
```

Пример работы:

> vvedite x = 11.0
>   vvedite m = 5
>   x = 11.0, f = 1.000
>   x = 11.0, m = 5, z = 1.609

Заметьте, `f` округлено с `0.9999...`. Что касается точности сравнения чисел с плавающей точкой - то Вы вводите эпсилон (точность), например, 10^-3 и сравниваете Ваше число с некоторым плюс или минус этот самый эпсилон. Например, посмотрите этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/399420/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-double).