# Проверки на ошибки вычисления выражения

Tags: c++, c, математика

Пытаюсь создать программу для проверки на ошибки вычисления следующего выражения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя неудачная попытка:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");
    float a, b, x;
    printf("Введите a,b,x:\n");
    scanf("%f%f%f", &a, &b, &x);
    if (x > b) {
            if (cosf(a * x) == 0.0f) {
                printf("error. tg = infinity");
            }
    }else if (x <= b){
            // Проблема тут
            if (cosf( sqrtf( fabs( pow(x, 2)))) == 0.0f) {
                printf("error. tg = infinity");
            }
    }

    printf("No errors");

    return 0;
}
```

Сделать проверку для x>b у меня получилось правильно, а вот для x<=b нет, по следующей причине:

> Где проверка с учетом погрешности e надо проверять, чтобы модуль
>   разности двух переменных был меньше погрешности. Никаких "==" не
>   должно быть.

Я пытался разобраться несколько дней, но все тщетно. Что значит погрешность e и разность каких двух переменных я должен использовать?

Comment: Полагаю, имеется в виду, что сравнивать числа с плавающей точкой на строгое равенство, вообще говоря, небезопасно. Чтобы узнать, почему так, ознакомьтесь с этими вопросами: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/399420).

Comment: Так как область значений косинуса `[-1; 1]`, а тангенс не обращается в бесконечность на этом отрезке, то не понятен смысл вашей проверки для случая `x <= b`.

Comment: @wololo, Здравствуйте,  проверка x<=b и правда скорее всего ненужна, сделал я её из-за незнания.
Насчёт небезопасности сравнения чисел с плавающей точкой знаю, поэтому пробовал использовать "== 0.0f", но это не подошло и преподаватель сказал мне про "Где проверка с учетом погрешности e надо проверять, чтобы модуль разности двух переменных был меньше погрешности. Никаких "==" не должно быть". Как мне стоит поступить?

Comment: Ну смотрите, вы проверяете, а не равно ли выражение `cosf(a * x)` в точности нулю. Не нужно так делать. Просто убедитесь, что выражение `cosf(a * x)` отклоняется от нуля на величину меньшую, чем некоторый, заданный вами `eps`. Например так: `fabs( cosf(a * x) ) < eps`. Сложно сказать наверняка, чему должен быть равен `eps`. В данном конкретном случае, попробуйте взять `eps` немного больший, чем `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()`, например, `eps = 1e-5f`.

Answer (score 2):

Это значит, что машинного нуля "нет" есть некое число, которое достоверно содержит некоторое количество нулей.

```
#define TOL 0.0000000000001
```

в коде

```
if fabs(x-y)<TOL ...
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за обратную связь. Скажите пожалуйста, а какие переменные в моем случае должны быть на месте x-y?

Comment: Все что вы сравниваете с нулем.